# Perfect hash for string with known number of keys

Tags: c++, hash, perfect-hash

Is it possible to have a perfect hash function from strings to integers, when the number of elements to be hashed is known? By perfect hash function I mean that there is no chance of collision.

Basically I am reading the signatures of multiple tables from a file (e.g. id, name, address). Different tables might have common attributes (e.g. name), but on *different* positions (i.e. columns). I would like to be able to ask something like: what is table1["name"]? or table2["name"].

UPDATE: I would prefer learning to do it myself than using something already out there.

Comment: As posed this question is likely to get closed... What do you call a perfect hash - what limitations do you place on it?

Comment: Yes it: just keep track of all unique strings you've seen so far, and assign consecutive integer ids to them. Now, what's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Floris a perfect hash function is just that: *perfect*. There are no collisions between the input key material and the generated hash indexes. The limitations are singular: no collisions.

Comment: Thank you. I have added the description of the problem.

Comment: Does it have to be minimal as well? Just curious.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. I was hoping to hash the name of the column to an array index, where the position of the column in the table would be stored. Does that answer? :)

Comment: @NPE: That doesn't really provide constant access.

Answer (score 4):

See [GNU gperf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/).

GNU gperf is a perfect hash function generator. For a given list of strings, it produces a hash function and hash table, in form of C or C++ code, for looking up a value depending on the input string. The hash function is perfect, which means that the hash table has no collisions, and the hash table lookup needs a single string comparison only.

Comment: Hm, am I allowed to integrate it into my project?

Comment: Indeed. And being a GNU project, it is properly-maintained. Use %language=C++ if you wish to use the output code in C++. Ref: [Gperf Declarations](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/manual/gperf.html#Gperf-Declarations).

Just beware that the resulting output code is [GNU GPL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/manual/gperf.html#Output-Copyright)

Comment: Thank you. I would prefer doing it myself though, just to learn how I might be able to achieve it, given the above problem description.

Comment: It's unclear that the the *output* code is GPL. The GNU/gperf folks don't seem to think so. They note that "gperf is under GPL, but that does not cause the output produced by gperf to be under GPL." Check out http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/manual/gperf.html#Output-Copyright for a more complete answer.